# Exporting nested lists to an excel file in Python

Tags: python, excel, list, export

So I have a list of lists.

For example:

```
    l = [[1,2,3],['a','b','c'],['a,b','d,c','a,e']]
```

I am having trouble exporting this properly because I need the two letters in the same cell, so if I use commas as a delimiter, it separates them. I have attached a photo of what i would want it to look like. I have already tried a few things but I am not sure how to do this. Any help would be great.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I believe your using the csv module, right? If so, you can just change the delimiter for the writer so that it won't separate.

Comment: Typically a CSV "field" which itself contains a comma would be double-quoted e.g. "a,b", so you need to figure out how to make that happen if you want to be able to open that file in excel and have "a,b" in a single cell.  It would be helpful if you could provide more detail on *exactly* how you're currently creating your CSV file.

Comment: Agree with @TimWilliams - will be easier to triage if you post how you are "exporting nested lists to an excel file".

Answer (score 0):

Export it as CSV first, which you can then open and save as a normal Excel workbook.

You use the built-in `csv` module to do that:

```
import csv

with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
    fc = csv.writer(f, lineterminator='\n')
    fc.writerows(l)
```